# SVG images not working at all in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, image, svg, microsoft-edge

Here is the html code that I've tried:

```
<html> <img src = "Contact2.svg" alt = "contact" /> </html>
```

Here is the output in every browser except Edge:
[Normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG5KQ.png)

Here is the output of the same file in Edge:
[Distorted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rxk4.png)

I've also tried using the svg tag directly in the file, but the result is the same. The svg in question is too big to attach (Stack Overflow won't let me add it), but I can find a way to upload it if necessary to diagnose the issue.

Is there really no way to include SVG files in Edge? If not, what are my options?

**edit** Here is the beginning of the svg file which was autogenerated by the svg creation software, vectr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="19 99 849.3178264315773 94" width="845.32" height="90"><defs><path d="M127.27 173.8C127.27 182.74 119.53 190 110 190C100.47 190 92.73 182.74 92.73 173.8C92.73 164.85 100.47 157.59 110 157.59C119.53 157.59 127.27 164.85 127.27 173.8Z" id="b1jyYeVtTq"></path><text id="b1lWAjMtn8" x="360.2" y="276.32" font-size="20" font-family="Open Sans" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" letter-spacing="0" alignment-baseline="before-edge" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -256.01590652958953 -115.99016726043811)" style="line-height:100%" xml:space="preserve" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge"><tspan x="360.2" dy="0em" alignment-baseline="before-edge" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" text-anchor="start">1</tspan></text><style id="opensansnormalnormal">
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("data:font/ttf;base64,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
```

Comment: If the SVG is not rendering properly, then it is the SVG we need to see. Your question currently contains no useful information with which to make even a guess at a diagnosis.  Try cutting down the size of your SVG to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem, then post that.  By size, I am referring to the file size (number of objects).

Comment: OK, thank you Paul ; I'll cut down the SVG and update the post.

Comment: You'll find basic information and techniques about using svgs in html here https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ also i recommend looking at this presentation: http://slides.com/sarasoueidan/building-better-interfaces-with-svg#/ after that you should have a good idea what might have probably gone wrong with your svg.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The solution turned out to be that Vectr, the software which I had used for the creation of my SVG icons, generated long and complicated code which Edge had trouble deciphering. Using Photoshop instead proved to be successful.